# eigen: How to get the max number from the upper matrix of the MatrixfXf?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I tried to use

`auto temp_matrix_upper = temp_matrix1.triangularView<Upper>();
 auto opt_maxium_error = temp_matrix_upper.maxCoeff();`

but I got a

> ‘class Eigen::TriangularView, 2>’ has no member named ‘minCoeff’; did you mean ‘coeff’?

Comment: sorry, upper triangular

Comment: The error does not seem to match the code you posted. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: That is an open feature request: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=885